# Logging RestTemplate's responses

Tags: java, logging, spring

I want to log responses using Spring's `RestTemplate`.
At first I thought I should do it using a `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor`, but since every set of requests should be logged to a different file, I figured out I should create a new `RestTemplate` with a new `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor` for every set of requests (though all other configurations are the same).

But I saw that `RestTemplate` is pretty expensive object to create, when about 70% of the creation time, is creating the `MessageConverters`.

So - is there a better way to implement this requirement ? Is it possible to share `MessageConverters` across multiple `RestTemplate` instances, hence, improve performance significantly ?

**EDIT**
Here is a sample of my code:

```
protected MyResponse<MyInterface> getInterfaces(RestTemplate restClient, RestParams inputParams, String cookie, File outputFile) {

    Request devInterfacesRequest = getRequest(RequestType.INTERFACES, inputParams, cookie);

    return restClient.postForObject(inputParams.getUrl(), devInterfacesRequest , new ParameterizedTypeReference<MyResponse<MyInterface>>(){});
}
```

Where can I add the outputFile ?

Comment: So your requirement is to log *RestTemplate* responses? (at the end of *execute(...)* method?). By the way. What's your SpringFramework version?

Comment: Yep. Exactly where the `interceptor` runs.

Comment: Are you familiar with Spring AOP? ;-). If don't I will try to offer to you a simple answer to give you some hints

Comment: A little bit. Could you elaborate?  I'm running Spring latest version.

Comment: How can I send a different file name to the Aspect?

Comment: Where's the info which decide where a log should go at? Url? In the response?

Comment: The client that calls the `postForObject() `.

Comment: Would you mind to share your client code? At least the point where it does invoke `postForObject() `? It's going to be easier for us to get in context

Answer (score 1):

Well I have been thinking in this question and this's what I get:

## Restrictions

Citing question's owner:

1. *To implement my own RestTemplate is to heavy*

> But I saw that RestTemplate is pretty expensive object to create, when about 70% of the creation time, is creating the MessageConverters.

2. *RestTemplate is not thread safe after construction. But it's not after construction*.See more [Is RestTemplate thread Safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22989500/is-resttemplate-thread-safe)

> Conceptually, it is very similar to the JdbcTemplate, JmsTemplate, and the various other templates found in the Spring Framework and other portfolio projects. This means, for instance, that the **RestTemplate is thread-safe once constructed**

*This last feature is suggesting to don't modify a RestTemplate after its construction. So I neither would add any new Interceptor nor remove it*

3. We miss many details about the system and it's requirements, boundaries,etc...
4. We don't know what these files are for. So it compromises the adequacy of the solution I propose.

## What do we have?

If I'm right, we have [Appache Log4J](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) configured. (*@Nati told me by chat*).

So I have decided to use Log4j as logger tool. However, please check out **Drawbacks** section. (*hope someone else reading this answer could dispel my doubts*)

**Why Log4j instead of my own File management?** Because I wanted to delegate to Log4j the next features: *access to files*, *usage of patterns*, *usage of filters (optional)*, *usage of levels*, ...

## Solution

### LoggerHelper

I have implemented a helper in order to make the solution portable through any layer with the less coupling possible.

```
package org.myworkouts.helper;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.log4j.FileAppender;
import org.apache.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout;


public class LoggerHelper {

    // Helper's own logger
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager
            .getLogger(LoggerHelper.class);
    private static final String DEFAULT_LOG_PATTERN = "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n";
    private static final String LOGGER_PREFIX = "logger";
    private static final String APPENDER_PREFIX = "appender";

    private static LoggerHelper instance = null;

    // Singleton
    private LoggerHelper() {
        super();
    }

    public static LoggerHelper getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new LoggerHelper();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    /**
     * Get the logger by its name or create if never was instanciated previously
     * 
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public Logger getCustomFileLogger(String filePath) throws IOException {
        String loggerName = resolveLoggerName(filePath);

        Logger logger = LogManager.exists(loggerName);
        if (logger == null) {
            LOGGER.info("Creating new Logger: ".concat(loggerName));
            logger = LogManager.getLogger(loggerName);
        }
        setLevel(logger, Level.INFO).addFileAppender(logger, filePath);
        return logger;
    }

    private LoggerHelper addFileAppender(Logger logger, String filePath)
            throws IOException {
        if (logger != null) {
            String appenderName = resolveAppenderName(filePath);
            if (logger.getAppender(appenderName) == null) {
                logger.addAppender(new FileAppender(new PatternLayout(
                        DEFAULT_LOG_PATTERN), filePath, Boolean.TRUE));
            }
        }
        return this;
    }

    private LoggerHelper setLevel(Logger logger, Level level) {
        if (logger != null) {
            logger.setLevel(level);
        }
        return this;
    }

    /* Optionl. Generate a custom name for a new Appender */
    private String resolveAppenderName(String filePath) {
        return APPENDER_PREFIX.concat(File.pathSeparator).concat(
                getNameWithoutExtension(filePath));
    }

    /* Optionl. Generate a custom name for a new Logger */
    private String resolveLoggerName(String filePath) {
        return LOGGER_PREFIX.concat(File.pathSeparator).concat(
                getNameWithoutExtension(filePath));
    }

    //Took from com.google.common.io.Files
    //I had it in my workspace but I didn't want to use it at this
    //class
    private String getNameWithoutExtension(String filePath) {
        String fileName = new File(filePath).getName();
        int dotIndex = fileName.lastIndexOf('.');
        return (dotIndex == -1) ? fileName : fileName.substring(0, dotIndex);
    }
}
```

### Implementation

Attaching the solution to owner's code

```
protected MyResponse<MyInterface> getInterfaces(RestTemplate restClient, RestParams inputParams, String cookie, File outputFile) {

    Request devInterfacesRequest = getRequest(RequestType.INTERFACES, inputParams, cookie);

     MyResponse<MyInterface> response =  restClient.postForObject(inputParams.getUrl(), devInterfacesRequest , new ParameterizedTypeReference<MyResponse<MyInterface>>(){});
     try{
           Logger customLogger = LoggerHelper.getInstance().getCustomFileLogger(outputFile.getPath());
           //... we can also to parse it to Json, XML, whatever...
           customLogger.info(response.toString());
     }catch(IOException ex){
          //... what do we have to do if logger could not be instanciated?
     }
     return response;
}
```

*Note*: *Implementation could be also moved to `getInterfaces` caller who has (I suppouse) a `for`bucle and also decide the `outputFile`. Then `getCustomFileLogger(...)` would be invoked just one time.*

### Test

```
public class LoggerHelperTest {

    public static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(LoggerHelperTest.class);

    @Test
    public void getCustomLoggerTest() throws IOException{
        Logger customLogger = LoggerHelper.getInstance().getCustomFileLogger("file.txt");
        Assert.assertNotNull("CustomLogger should not be null",customLogger);
        Assert.assertEquals("CustomLogger's level should be INFO by default",Level.INFO, customLogger.getLevel());
        Assert.assertTrue("CustomLogger's name should contain file's name on its name",customLogger.getName().contains("file"));
        customLogger.info("Trace 1");
        customLogger.info("Trace 2");
        customLogger.info("Trace 3");
    }
}
```

### file.txt

The output I got

```
2016-05-03 13:38:56 INFO  logger:file:47 - Trace 1
2016-05-03 13:38:56 INFO  logger:file:48 - Trace 2
2016-05-03 13:38:56 INFO  logger:file:49 - Trace 3
```

## Doubts

This's a suggestion. It's opened to suggestions or improvements. I also have my own doubts about my solution. (*I didn't stress the solution*):

1. Is **File outputFile** locked (opened) by any other process? Then IOException will be thrown.
2. Home any differents **outputFile** are? 10,100,1000? Can we hold that much of Loggers in Log4j?
3. Are these **outputFile** going to be moved in runtime? If any is moved/deleted/replaced log4j wont be able to keep logging in it.
4. Shall we catch IOException instead of let it go?. I delegate to LoggerHelper user to decice what to do...

I have used Log4j because I have had in mind that the requirement is to keep loggers separated printing everyone on its own file. But I expect they only contain log traces (*for further reviews or debugs*).

However if file's content matters, if content is important for us, the solution is not suitable.

If content matters and I don't want to implement a *file management*, I would think on storage these logs in *noSQL* db's (mongoDB or any other more suitable for our platform) which also is capable to support a high volume of data. Data can be obtained later with proper requests

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, but I wanted to log the response "on the wire".  With your implementation,  in case I have a conversion error,  the response won't be logged.

Comment: If to log Is so critic, then do the conversion inside my try/catch. If conversion fails, let the runtime exception go... Anyways any good mapper/converter should not fail. If you do your own file management a IOExcpetion can be thrown any time. The problem is still there. Unless you wish also log 'HTTP request/ response headers, body, status, etc. Then my solution is not suitable for you

Comment: The thing is conversion may drop unmapped fields, and I want the exact response, as received. Char by char.

Comment: Then you need to log `HttpClient` response I guess. And this component is out of your scope. Lets see if anyone else comes with a suitable solution:-)